# How can I get Bootstrap to put my thumbnails in 2 columns rather than 1 in 800 x 600 and below?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Here is [a live example](http://staging.thesecoya.com/apt605/).

For the big resolutions, it works fine - you will see the 'popular products' at the bottom all in one row.

But if you resize your window to say 800 x 600, and scroll down you will see all the thumbnails in 1 column.

How can I get that to be in 2 columns? Or does Bootstrap not support that?

i.e. I don't want to have to change any of the logic in the default CSS files - I just wanted to see if I was doing anything wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: It is possible to do what you want. The way it works now is more efficient for mobile devices to display in a long list that way the flow is much more cleaner. So if I understand you want to have 2 Popular products/ 170x120px images display side by side on each line?

Comment: Yes...that's exactly what I am trying to do. Without having to dig into the media queries in the CSS. The issue is that the div with class `side-img med` has a width of 100%, where the image has a width of just 170px.

Comment: @marcamillion media queries will definitely work for you. Another approach would be to use javascript (jQuery) but that's less elegant.

Comment: @marcamillion I see 2 columns when I resize my browser on the example. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid you cannot get two columns in the mobile version with pure Bootstrap. The default media queries rearrange any `.spanX` in one single column:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  ...
  [class*="span"] {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    ...
  }
}
```

And nesting an `.spanX` within another `.spanX` doesn't work either. What you could do is to extend the default Bootstrap classes with an special version of `.span2` for your purposes:

http://jsfiddle.net/LPsQy/

The new `.my-span2` behaves as a regular `.span2`, but for the mobile media query works as a fluid `.span6` (takes ~50% percent of the width).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not trivial to do it without changing Bootstrap's CSS on your own. If you cannot do it nice, here is the ugly solution:

1. Generated [custom](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html) Bootstrap without responsive "Narrow tablets and below (<767px)" option. Lets call it **Big**.
2. Generated [custom](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html) Bootstrap with only one media (I choosed "Tablets to desktops (767-979px)"). Lets call it **Small**.
3. In Small CSS I removed lines: `@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {`,  `@media (max-width: 979px) {`, and their closing brackets `}`. These are grid system and navbar.
4. Create your own CSS with following content:

Your new `css/bootstrap.css`

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  ... paste Small CSS here ...
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  ... paste Big CSS here ...
}
```

See [example](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/354209/bootwo/index.html).

**Note 1:** It may still be not exactly what you want, because bellow 767px the grid system is fixed 2-columned and you may prefer fluid 2-column.

**Note 2:** Some more changes are required cor `hidden-*` and `visible-*` classes to work.

**Note 3:** You can take some time to diff the CSS files to see what really differs them.

Bootstrap was created to make easy solution to common problem. If your problem is not common, then the solution will not be easy ;) In your case you need to recreate your own CSS by selecting some parts of Bootstrap's...